# Macro not locating ws in other wb when WorkbookOpen sub is ran

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

My codes seems to only locate the worksheets in the workbook that is currently opening. When I go back after the workbook is already open and hit F5 on the Workbook_Open sub it then locates all the worksheets in every open workbook like it should. Not sure if this is a limitation on Excel. Any pointers are helpful.

Essentially the goal of the code is to make clicking hyperlinks in other workbooks execute a macro housed in this workbook. If anyone knows of a better way to do that I am all ears.

In "ThisWorkbook"

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()

 Call CreateClassesNEWWB

 End Sub
```

In "Module 2"

```
Public objCollection As Collection

Sub CreateClassesNEWWB()

'allows hyperlinks in other workbooks to be driven off sub in this workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim HyperlinksClass As cHyperlinks

'Create A New Instance Of The Collection
Set objCollection = New Collection
'Loop All Worksheets

For Each ws In Worksheets
    'Create A New Class For This Worksheet
  Set HyperlinksClass = New cHyperlinks
    'Add The Worksheet To The Class
  Set HyperlinksClass.obj = ws
    'Add The Class To The Collection
  objCollection.Add HyperlinksClass
Next ws


End Sub
```

In Class Module "cHyperlinks"

```
Private WithEvents Pws As Worksheet

Private Sub Pws_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

Select Case Target.TextToDisplay
Case "Transpose": Call TransposeWire
Case "Research": Call Research
End Select

End Sub

Property Set obj(ByVal objWS As Worksheet)

Set Pws = objWS

End Property
```

Comment: There's no code here which loops through all open workbooks, only the worksheets of whatever happens to be the ActiveWorkbook

Comment: What are you proposing then Tim? I have already tried adding in a For Each wb loop along with the For each ws loop and still did not get my desired result. It doesnt seem to matter that the other wb is not an active workbook when I execute the code directly via F5 on the sub.

Comment: I would propose a `For Each wb in Workbooks` loop, wrapped around your `For Each ws in Worksheets` (except it would be `wb.Worksheets`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub CreateClassesNEWWB()

'allows hyperlinks in other workbooks to be driven off sub in this workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim HyperlinksClass As cHyperlinks

'Create A New Instance Of The Collection
Set objCollection = New Collection

For Each wb In Workbooks             '<loop workbooks
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets     '<loop worksheets
        objCollection.Add LinkHandler(ws)
    Next ws
Next wb

End Sub

'I like "factory" functions partly to be sure
'  I'm creating all objects as independent instances...
Function LinkHandler(ws As Worksheet) As cHyperlinks
    Dim rv As New cHyperlinks
    Set rv.obj = ws
    Set LinkHandler = rv
End Function
```

Comment: looks like I was missing the wb.Worksheets part when I was tried the For Each wb.  Added that in and now it seems we are good to go. Thank you kindly Tim.

Comment: Might you know of a way to kick off this Macro anytime a new workbook is open not just when this workbook is opened? This would be so that if they open a workbook after this workbook a new class of objects will be established.

Comment: Yes you can use Application events: see for example - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn254092.aspx  Note also that each *workbook* object has a `SheetFollowHyperlink` event which gets the source worksheet as a parameter in addition to the Hyperlink object.  If you capture that event instead of the individual sheet events you have fewer objects to sink events from.

Comment: Got it all set up and going appreciate the links. Thank again Tim.